# Moving files with folder structure by age to different drive

Tags: command-line, scripts, find

I have a folder called `Research` (which also includes sub-folders).

I wish to regularly move files from `Research` that are greater than 6 months old, to a different folder called `Research_Archive`, which is on a different drive. Files >6 months will be deleted from `Research`.
The folder `Research_Archive` will reproduce the sub-folder structure of `Research`.

The script would run periodically, thus Research_Archive will be updated.

I saw a script like this:

```
find . -type f -mtime +5 -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    dir="${file%/*}"
    mkdir -p ../rootarchive/"$dir"
    mv "$file" ../rootarchive/"$file"
done
```

But as a newbie to scripting, I'm totally confused by its relative paths. For example, my source path is: `/home/me/Documents/Research/` and destination would be: `/media/me/drive21/Documents/Research_Archive/`.

And I'm not sure if running the above script more than once, would recreate the `Research_Archive` folder again. And how would permissions be set on the `Research_Archive` folder (when I tried testing, I was locked out from viewing view file manger of the created folder).

Any help/specific examples will be appreciated.

Comment: If run in your home directory it shouldn't lock you out, and it will produce an error after the first use since the folder will already be created

Answer (score 2):

This script should help in this regards:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

from=$1
destination=$2
if [[ -d "$from" && -s "$from" ]]; then

        # extract the name of the sub directory
        # to be create
        src=$(sed -r 's/.*\/(Research).*/\1/' <<< "$from")

        if [[ -d /media/me/drive21/Documents/Research_Archive/ ]]; then

                destination=/media/me/drive21/Documents/Research_Archive/

                if [[ ! -d "$destination/$src" ]]; then                       

                        mkdir "$destination/$src"
                        newdes="$destination/$src"
                        find "$from" -type f -mtime +5 -print0 -exec mv {} "$newdes" \;
                else
                        cd "$destination"
                        find "$from" -type f -mtime +5 -print0 -exec mv {} "$newdes" \;

                fi

         else
                exit 1
         fi
else
        exit 1
fi
```

Usage:

```
chmod +x mv.sh
./mv.sh /home/me/Documents/Research/  /media/me/drive21/Documents/Research_Archive
```

Using a `udev` rule to automate the moving of the files to external storage:

1. Alter the code to work with this setup:

```bsh
    #!/bin/bash

    from=$1
    destination=$2
    if [[ -d "$from" && -s "$from" ]]; then

            # extract the name of the sub directory
            # to be create
            src=$(sed -r 's/.*\/(arch).*/\1/' <<< "$from")

            if [[ -d "/media/me/drive21/Documents/Research_Archive/" ]];then


                 destination="/media/me/drive21/Documents/Research_Archive/"

                    if [[ ! -d "$destination/$src" ]]; then

                            cd "$destination"
                            mkdir "$src"

                            find "$from" -type f -mtime -5 -exec mv {} "$src" \;
                    else
                            cd "$destination"
                            find "$from" -type f -mtime -5 -exec mv {} "$src" \;

                    fi

            else
                    exit 1
            fi
    else
            exit 1
    fi
```

2. Set up mount device event:

   - Create a `.rule` file:

     ```udev
     KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTR{removable}=="1", ATTRS{serial}=="07083395757D2761", MODE="0777", RUN+="/home/me/mv.sh /home/me/Documents/Research/ /media/me/drive21/Documents/Research_Archive"
     ```
   - call this `90-move.rules` and place in `/etc/udev/rules.d` directory
   - Use `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sd*` to get the needed information about your external storage device.

     [image]
3. Now all need do is plugin your device and once it's identified by the `rule` set, the files should be moved. Please tweak the code to the way it will work best for you.

Source:

http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/ch07s03.html

https://wiki.debian.org/udev

https://www.linux.com/news/udev-introduction-device-management-modern-linux-system

Comment: Thanks. Moved the files fine. But did not recreate the *sub-folders* of Research in Research_Archive. It just moved files into the main folder.

Comment: Also, how would I call this script, if wanted to automate at boot or run as a cron? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for working on this. But when testing your updated script using './mv.sh /home/me/Documents/Research/  /media/me/drive21/Documents/Research_Archive', it still does not create the sub-folder of Research in Research_Archive. It still moves all files in the main Research_Archivefolder, which is now located in a series of other folders: home/me/Documents/.../Research_Archive

Comment: Is this with the `run at boot` setup?

Comment: No, just ran the command /mv.sh...  in terminal

Comment: I ran it on my system and it works.

Comment: See the updated answer